# Java Spring Boot MongoDB Configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I am new and I try to develop an API with Java Spring Boot.
I have a problem with MongoDB Config and I have no problem in another project. I don't understand why.
I have already looked but the solutions proposed do not work.

**SBApplication.java :**

```
package basket;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = { "basket.instrastructure.dao" })
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration //(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SBApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SBApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**BasketRepository.java :**

```
package basket.infrastructure.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import basket.domaine.model.Basket;

@Repository 
public interface BasketRepository extends MongoRepository<Basket, Long> {

    public ArrayList<Basket> findAll();
    public Basket findById(String id);    
}
```

**ItemRepository.java :**

```
package basket.infrastructure.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import basket.domaine.model.Item;


@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, Long> {
    public Item findByName(String name);
    public ArrayList<Item> findAll();
    public Item findById(String id);
}
```

**MongoConfig.java :**

```
package basket.application.components;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories ("basket.infrastructure.dao")
public class MongoConfig extends  AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://owner:AAAAA@basketcluster-feebu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        return mongoClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And I have this error

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Can you help me to understand my mistake.
Thank you, any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you forgot to add the port in your url

Comment: You can refer this, https://paulsofts.com/crud-operations-how-to-integrate-spring-boot-with-monogdb

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about your MongoDB URI? Usually, the URI has the form `mongodb://localhost:27017/foo`.

If you use **Spring-boot** instead of using a Configuration bean I suggest you use *application.properties* file. In this file write a property likes `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/foo` and **Spring-boot** automatically injects the properties in MongoClient without any configuration at the code level.

Comment: I will test with the application.porperties file
I had a project in which I had no problem but I redid with DDD architecture. And now I have the problem.
The database is on the server mongoDB. And in the doc I can connect to the data base with :
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
    "mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/");

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

Answer (score 0):

Try as @Federico Gatti said by configuring Mongo iuth properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=MongoDatabaseName
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Use properties file to configure your database with application and let the spring boot do everything for you with db configuration.

Go to the resources/application.properties file, and add the following content to it:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydatabase
```

That will allow your application to correctly connect to your MongoDB database.

Also, Go to the main application class, and add the following annotation before its declaration:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = foo.class)
```